# golangci-lint not showing errors on vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, golangci-lint

I'm trying to integrate golangci-lint with vscode.  This is my settings file in vscode

```
  "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
  "go.lintFlags": ["--fast"],
  "go.liveErrors": {
    "enabled": true,
    "delay": 500
  },
  "go.lintOnSave": "workspace",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures": {
    "diagnostics": true
  }
```

However none of the errors/warnings show up on vscode.  Initially it was showing up but suddenly disappeared.  Also on another note, I know the linting tool in turn use a number of other linters like `errcheck` `ineffassign` and so on, do I have to install them separately ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by removing `--fast` flag from the configuration, and rerunning linter via VS Code plugin, then adding it back.

I suspect it had something to do with the cache the `--fast` flag is using:
https://golangci-lint.run/usage/faq/#why-running-with---fast-is-slow-on-the-first-run